# Prove that it is impossible to define $0$ and "multiplication" on $\Bbb N^2$ such that it becomes a model of **PA**

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms

Suppose we define addition on $\Bbb N^2$ as $(x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$. I need to prove that there is no way to define $0$ andd multiplication so that becomes a model of the Peano Axioms **PA**.

A hint says that every member of $\Bbb N$ is either even or odd. But I cannot find the connection between this fact and the question.

Could someone please tell me how can I see it from this hint? Or any other ways are also appreciated.

My version of **PA** is stated as follows:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The title says something different (and false) than what the question says.

Comment: Anyway, what you wrote makes no sense. Check the first equation and please fix the typos.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Sorry for the typo. Thanks a lot for pointing it out. I have fixed it.

Comment: what has multiplication to do with peano axioms?

Comment: $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are odd but $(0,1)+(1,1)=(1,2)$ is also odd.

Comment: @user463383 I think in this argument, firstly we need to define odd and even number in $\Bbb N^2$. Could you please explain a bit more about how we can define it, and then how to put it into the **PA** and get a contradiction?

Comment: The definition should be the same as in PA: A number $x$ is even when there is $y$ such that $x=y+y$. Odds numbers are those that are not even. Also, take into account that in PA you can prove that the sum of two odd numbers is an even number.

Comment: "I need to prove that there is no way to define $0$ andd multiplication so that becomes a model of the Peano Axioms **PA**." ....
... so that *what* becomes a model of PA?  I don't understand what you need to prove ...

Comment: @Bram28 I think this is: $N^2$ as the underlying class together with the function "addition", "multiplication" and "0", becomes a model of **PA**. That is, $N^2$ as the underlying class together with the function "addition", "multiplication" and "0" satisfies the peano axioms.

Comment: @user464003 OK, so the given addition is used as an interpretation for $+$ ... what about the $^+$ (typically the successor)?  Or maybe there is already a problem with trying to define the $0$ and $*$ for $N^2$ and satisfying the Peano Axioms ....

Comment: The addition is incompatible with the successor function and induction principle. That is the main crux.

Comment: [Please type out the math.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116051/259305)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite know what to do with the hint ... but here is a problem with trying to make $\mathbb{N}^2$ the domain of a model where $+$ is interpreted as given:

Using the Peano Axioms you can prove:

$$\forall x \forall y (\exists z \ x + z^+ = y \lor x = y \lor \exists z \ y + z^+ = x)$$

However, this will not be true for $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ (or any $(m,n)$ and $(n,m)$ with $m\not = n$), because with the $+$ as given, there is no $(m,n) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ such that $(0,1)+(m,n)=(1,0)$, we don't have that $(0,1) = (1,0)$, and there is no $(m,n) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ such that either $(1,0)+(m,n)=(0,1)$

So, you already cannot make a model with $\mathbb{N}$ as the domain and the $+$ as given, no matter how you would interpret $\overline{0}$ or $\cdot$.

UPDATE

OK, so here is something you can do with the hint: Given that a number $x$ is even if and only if there is some $y$ such that $y+y=x$, it follows that the only even numbers in your domain are $(2m,2n)$ with $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. Defining a number $x$ to be odd if and only if there is some $y$ such that $x = (y + y) + \overline{0}^+$, you can use the Peano axioms (especially the induction axiom PA3) to prove that:

1) every number has to be odd or even, and

2) that any odd number plus odd number is an even number.

So, this means by 1) that $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are odd, which by 2) means that $(0,1)+(1,0)=(1,1)$ should be even ... but clearly it is not.

Comment: If, as user463383 suggested in a comment, we define "odd" to mean "not even", then the hint "every number is even or odd" becomes tautologous and therefore useless. But if one defines "$x$ is odd" to mean $x+1$ is even, then the hint works. Like your answer, it yields the information that the proposed addition is already hopeless, regardless of any attempted multiplication. (More formally: $N^2$ with the given addition isn't a model of Presburger arithmetic.)

Comment: One can prove from Peano's axioms that "not even" is equivalent to "successor of an even number."

Comment: I appreciate it! Very nice argument which is easier then the way that the hint points out! Thanks!

Comment: @user464003 You're welcome!  I did add to my post the proof that it's not going to work on the basis of even and odd .... but I agree, I think my original proof (which effectively shows that you're going to run into trouble with the linear order of the elements as mandated by the induction axiom) gets a bit more at the 'heart' of the problem here.

Comment: A nit pick: the even numbers are $\{\,(2m,2n) : m,n \in \mathbb{N}\,\}$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Ah, yes, of course, thanks!